# MongoDB import inc

Tags: java, mongodb

I am following a Java tutorial on MongoDB and I was on this [example](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#update-multiple-documents):

```
UpdateResult updateResult = collection.updateMany(lt("i", 100), inc("i", 100));
```

When I try to run it in my IDE, I get an error over `inc`. It says that `The method inc(String, int) is undefined for the type myClassName`. How do I import it to my class? I have searched around but no answer.

Thanks

Comment: is there more code ? What is `myClassName` ? That method is part of `Updates` class.

Comment: myClassName is just a random name that I gave to the class. This class contains a main method and I am running all those methods that are mentioned in that tutorial like insertion, querying, updating, deleting, etc, in this main class.

Comment: Can you add this static import `import static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.inc;` and see it helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the static import

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.inc;
```

to the class.